# Unable to find a specification for 'React-RCTFabric' depends upon by 'RNGestureHandler'

Tags: react-native

I have this issue on react native when im trying to make pod install. I can make the build on android but on ios i get some problems to make the pod install. I also try to clean node modules and reinstall all several times.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "caremeMobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx": "^3.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/devtools": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.186",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "cron-parser": "^4.5.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.10",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "metro-config": "^0.66.2",
    "native-base": "2.15.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.3",
    "react-native": "0.71.1",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-bluetooth-state-manager": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1276.0",
    "react-native-circular-action-menu": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^6.22.1",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.8",
    "visualtis-messaging-service": "file:./visualtis-messaging-service-1.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
{
  "name": "caremeMobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx": "^3.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/devtools": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.186",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "cron-parser": "^4.5.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.10",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "metro-config": "^0.66.2",
    "native-base": "2.15.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.3",
    "react-native": "0.71.1",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-bluetooth-state-manager": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1276.0",
    "react-native-circular-action-menu": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^6.22.1",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.8",
    "visualtis-messaging-service": "file:./visualtis-messaging-service-1.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

And this is my podfile

````
`require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'mobile' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'mobileTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
`
````

[Photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8b5p.png)

i tried to change Podfile for the default resulted by react-native init "project" and i get the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try to bump the version of `react-native-gesture-handler` package.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bump `react-native-gesture-handler` and also `react-native-safe-area-context`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34430526)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the version of `react-native-gesture-handler` to `"^2.12.0"` in `package.json` resolved the issue for me.